# Sequences Vs Count for auto-increment

Tags: oracle, performance, sequence, query-performance

Can some one please tell me the exact difference between the following statements ,

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ((select count(column-name) from table-name2)+1);
```

here i am using the count function to auto-increment the value..

The same functionality can be done with **`sequences`**..

what will happen when both of this queries are executed and also please tell me the drawbacks of using the **count** over **sequence**

Comment: The approach using `count()` is broken and will not work  in a multi-user environment (or *if* you do get it right using table-locks and serialization it won't scale and will be dead-slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count(column_name) will give numbers of not-null records from the table "Table1".

Sequence would return a number irrespective of number of records in the table "Table1" .
Sequence can be used globally ,not only specific to a table.

if you require a digit on basic of records in table use Count function.
if you  require just a running serial number use sequence.